# Highlight Single Page Ancestor

Tags: php, functions, css, wp-list-pages

I have a calendar called [Event Organizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/event-organiser/) that I have been customizing: http://joshrodg.com/open/calendar/. You'll notice if you click on one of the blue events you are redirected to a page that looks like: http://joshrodg.com/open/calendar/event/pastor-bible-study/.

Right now, when someone goes to that page nothing in the navigation bar is highlighted, but I'd like the navigation item Calendar to be highlighted. I am using `wp_list_pages` to create my navigation.

I think I've seen something like this before, but I'm not sure what I'm after. Basically, the child page of the the Calendar page would highlight the main page Calendar in the navigation bar when you are on that page.

I thought that would involve styling `li.current_page_ancestor`, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I don't know if it's easier to add this functionality for all child pages for any main navigation item (i.e. Home, About, Ministries, Calendar, Location, Contact), but that would work to.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Your events aren't actually child pages, they're a separate custom post type. You could probably target that menu item on event pages if you used [`body_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) for the body tag to identify when you're viewing an event.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for letting me know that they are custom post types...that definitely helps! I installed this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-parents/ which works, just trying to figure out the logic behind it.

Comment: @milo, this is something that would work, but it's too specific. I would have to know the ID of the page in the menu. If I applied this theme to another WordPress install, I would need to go in and tweak the CSS in order for everything to work properly. The plugin is a better solution because I just activate it and I don't have to change anything in the theme...although, I was hoping for a function or something, which would be 10 times better than a plugin.

Comment: You can do it with a custom walker like in [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/130883/4771), I imagine that's what the plugin uses.

Comment: Thanks @Milo! I'm definitely looking into this one, still trying to understand how to implement the custom walker :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I never did figure out how to do this without the plugin I mentioned. What fixed the issue was installing: [wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-parents](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-parents). This plugin has a Settings page which allows you to choose the page that is the parent for your custom post type, then it adds the classes necessary to the `wp_list_pages` menu.